# Tokeninput foreach value after submit and sort the custom and exist value

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, submit, jquery-tokeninput

I using the jQuery Tokeninput autocomplete plugin from http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/
When I try to submit the value to my php handler, i can't figure out how to do this

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?=base_lang_url("addtags/test")?>" method="post">
<input id="tags" name="tags">
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#tags').tokenInput("../ajax/getTags", {
    allowCustomEntry: true,
    propertyToSearch: "name",
    tokenValue: "name",
    tokenLimit: 5,
    preventDuplicates: true,
    theme:"facebook",
    noResultsText: "No results",
    searchingText: "Searching..."
});
```

The JS i just to show how i have set it up but i think it not so important with this.

**PHP**

```
if(trim($this->input->post("room_tags")) != ""){
    $tags = explode(",",trim($this->input->post("room_tags")));
    foreach($tags as $value){
        if(preg_replace( "/[^0-9]/", "",$value)){
            $tag_int[] = $value;
        }else{
            $tag_string[] = $value;
        }
    }

    $this->load->model("tags_model");
    $tag_find = $this->tags_model->findTags($tag_int);

    if(is_array($tag_find) && is_array($tag_string)){
        $all_tags = array_merge($tag_find,$tag_string);
    }elseif(is_array($tag_find) && isset($tag_find)){
        $all_tags = $tag_find;
    }elseif(isset($tag_string) && is_array($tag_string)){
        $all_tags = $tag_string;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
        echo print_r($all_tags);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => Hej
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => Hvor
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tag_name] => Hvad
        )

    [3] => 'wegehe'
    [4] => 'afqfq'
)
```

**I like to have it like this:**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Hej
        [1] => Hvor
        [2] => Hvad
        [3] => wegehe
        [4] => afqfq
    )
```

Without ' on the strings.

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code before

```
echo '<pre>';



$all_tags_copy = $all_tags;
$all_tags = array();

foreach($all_tags as $key => $value){
 if(is_array($value) && count($value) > 0){
  foreach($value as $v2){
   if(!empty($v2)){
    $all_tags[] = $v2;
   }
  }
 }else{
  if(!empty($value)){
   $all_tags[] = $value;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I didn't tested, please test it and post your feedback